# How to remove duplicate rows from a Inner join query in mysql

Tags: mysql, html

I have four tables which are

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Englishword (WordId int NOT NULL,WordName varchar(100) NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (WordId))

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MeaningInAmharicforEnglish (MeaningidA int(11) NOT NULL,WordIdA int NOT NULL,MeaningNameA varchar(50) NOT NULL,WordclassA varchar (50) NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (MeaningidA),FOREIGN KEY (WordIdA) REFERENCES Englishword(WordId) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE) ENGINE = InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MeaningInTigrgnaforEnglish (MeaningidT int(11) NOT NULL,WordIdT int NOT NULL,MeaningNameT varchar(50) NOT NULL,WordclassT varchar (50) NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (MeaningidT),FOREIGN KEY (WordIdT) REFERENCES Englishword(WordId) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE) ENGINE = InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MeaningInEnglishforEnglish (MeaningidE int(11) NOT NULL,WordIdE int NOT NULL,MeaningNameE varchar(100) NOT NULL,WordclassE varchar (50) NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (MeaningidE),FOREIGN KEY (WordIdE) REFERENCES Englishword(WordId) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

and I have a data in the 
Englishword

> 1     go

I have a data in the 
MeaningInEnglishforEnglish

> 1 1 hello verb
>   2 1 hello noun

I have a data in the 
MeaningInAmharicforEnglish

> 1 1 ራቀ verb
>   2 1 ራቀ noun

I have a data in the 
MeaningInTigrgnaforEnglish

> 1 1 ሄደ verb
>   2 1 ሄደ noun

I have used the folloing query

```
SELECT  WordId,
WordName,WordclassE,MeaningidE,MeaningNameE,WordclassA,MeaningidA,MeaningNameA,WordclassT,MeaningidT,MeaningNameT

FROM Englishword AS E, MeaningInEnglishforEnglish AS EM, MeaningInAmharicforEnglish AS AE, MeaningInTigrgnaforEnglish AS TE

WHERE (E.WordId = EM.WordIdE)
AND (E.WordId = AE.WordIdA)
AND (E.WordId = TE.WordIdT)
```

this gives me the following result :

```
 WordId     WordName  WordclassE  MeaningidE  MeaningNameE  WordclassA  MeaningidA   
 1              go      verb       1            hello         verb     1   
 1              go      verb      1             hello         verb         1 
 1              go      verb      1             hello         verb         1
 1              go      verb      1             hello         verb         1
 1              go      verb      2             hello         verb         2 
 1              go      verb      2             hello         verb          2 
 1              go      verb      2             hello         verb          2 
 1              go      verb      2             hello         verb          2
```

and the same too the other fields repeated depending of the vale they have in the table ,how ever i want to be the result like this

```
WordId    WordName MeaningidE wordclass MeaningNameE WordclassA MeaningidA MeaningNameA 
1          go         1         verb       hello      verb       1             ራቀ 
Null       Null       2         verb       hello      verb       2             ራቀ
```

AND THE SAME IS FOR THE REST FIELD

hHow can I write a query that display as the desired one by removing the duplicate rows ?

Answer (score 0):

If you could please format your answer, that would be great. It's not a lot anyone could understand from the way it is at this point. 
I suppose your solution is using a `GROUP BY column_name` for the field you are getting the duplicates on.
Try to format your questions as clearly as possible next time.

Comment: i have used gruop by  of the repeated column it gives me the same no change my objective is i have a word in english that word have a meaning in english and in other language which are local to us and i want when i user writes the english word in the search box it should bring the meaning in three of the language